# NullInjectorError NbStepper Angular

Tags: angular, web-applications, nebular

I'm trying to add a stepper in my angular app but after i added the module, this error appears:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NbStepComponent -> InjectionToken Nebular Stepper Component]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NbStepComponent -> InjectionToken Nebular Stepper Component]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Nebular Stepper Component!
```

This is the AppModule:

```
import {
  NbThemeModule,
  NbLayoutModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbSidebarService,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbMenuService,
  NbActionsModule,
  NbInputModule,
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCalendarModule,
  NbDatepickerModule,
  NbCheckboxModule,
  NbToastrModule,
  NbDialogModule,
  NbSpinnerModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbCalendarRangeModule,
  NbTreeGridModule,
  NbContextMenuModule,
  NbStepperModule,
  NbListModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
```

And after that:

```
 imports: [
  ...
    Ng2SmartTableModule,
    NbStepperModule,
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
...
```

I'm using `@nebular/theme 3.5.0` version.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: You sure you are added module instead of component in `AppModule`? Are you sure you added it in `Iimports` section? Can you show your `AppModule`?

Comment: @KamLar Yes, i'm pretty sure the module is imported, and vsc doesn't pop up any error.

Comment: Don't directly import in app.module try importing in sub-module. It worked for me.

Comment: @ShubhamBhokare how? The company i work for only has a global app module in the apps structure.

Comment: What `Angular` version do you use? Where do you use `NbStepComponent`? How you create it? Programmatically? Or inside of template? How you create this template?

Comment: @KamLar NbStepComponent is from nebular, a set of components for angular, i only have to install it as a dependency and i can use all the components that nebular has. I already use a lot of their components with no problem, but i have this particular error only with the stepper. I use angular 7 locally but my global is 9.

Comment: According to this: https://auth0.com/blog/angular-9-whats-new/ if you are using component inside of another component which was created programmaticaly (using for example `ModalService`) and not anywhere else, you might have to add this to `entryComponents` to let angular know, that you are actually using it.That's why I asked you how you use it.

Comment: @KamLar I already checked that, but still doesn't work, idk what else to do